# The Question of By Reference Recommended on Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference, byref

This is something I needed to clear up awhile back. In PHP 5.3+, I wanted to ask if this improves performance on a very large array result? And do you have a way I can demonstrate the proof?

```
$synonyms = & MobyThesaurus::GetSynonyms("check");
```

Note the ampersand (by reference, instead of by value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses copy-on-write behind the scenes. Meaning, values are only copied when they're altered. Until then there's no copying going on and `$synonyms` basically acts as a reference anyway. If you're only ever *reading* from the array, there should be no difference in performance.

Once you *are* writing to the array, it *does* make quite a bit of difference in *functionality* whether the variable is a reference or not. Don't use references unless you mean to, or you may introduce funky side effects into your app.

There are a many optimizations going on behind the scenes, don't expect to be able to optimize it any more with such "tricks". PHP is the wrong language for being clever with pointer/reference acrobatics. :-)